# Time limit between keystrokes while filtering asp:DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

I am working on a ASP.NET Webforms page and have an issue with the behaviour of the asp:DropDownList: If a user opens the list with click and starts input via keyboard to search for a specific entry the "timeout" between two keystrokes is too quick for slow typing users.

Example:

List:

```
(< = cursor)

ABC<
BCD
CDE
DEF
EFG
```

User "Quickuser" wants to filter for "CDE". If he quickly types "CDE" within a couple of ms everything works:

```
ABC
BCD
CDE<
DEF
EFG
```

Quickuser can now press enter and is finished.

User "Slowuser" wants to filter for "CDE". He presses "C", the cursor goes to "CDE":

```
ABC
BCD
CDE<
DEF
EFG
```

The user is now searching for the letter "D" and unable to see the cursor. After 1-2s he presses "D":

```
ABC
BCD
CDE
DEF<
EFG
```

Finally after 1-2s he presses "E":

```
ABC
BCD
CDE
DEF
EFG<
```

The cursor is now on "EFG" => Wrong selection.

My question is: Is there any on-board property, general config, browser setting etc. I am missing to give Slowuser enough time to complete his input?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist?view=netframework-4.8 didn't help

Thank you!

Edit:

Markup of the DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAbc" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="ddlAbc_TextChanged" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

Items are added in code behind once in Page_Load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
'''
'(Unrelated stuff)
'''
  If Not (IsCallback Or IsPostBack) Then
   '''
   '(Unrelated stuff)
   '''
   FillValues()
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub FillValues()
 '''
 '(Unrelated stuff)
 '''
   ddlAbc.Items.Clear()
 '''
 '(Unrelated stuff, Select data into Recordset Rst)
 '''
 If Not (Rst.EOF And Rst.BOF) Then
  Rst.MoveFirst()
  Do While Not Rst.EOF
    Call ddlAbc.Items.Add(Trim(Rst.Fields("Def").Value.ToString()))
    Rst.MoveNext()
  Loop
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Need more info. This is not a typical DDL with LIstItems. In a typical DDL, I type D, I go to entries starting with D; I type G, I go to entries starting with G. There's something missing in your description. Show us the markup of your DDL.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for you reply. I edited my original post with markup and how the items are added. But imho there's nothing special going on. What you're saying is right. But IF you type quick enough your input is recognized as a string and you're able to write the whole text. Here is a good example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PdyOeI Click into DDL for product selection. Quickly type "mobile" => cursor stays at "Mobile". Now type "mob" wait 1s and type "i" => cursor selects "IPad"

Comment: Sry, thought for sure there was an autocomplete issue, but i retested locally and see what you mean. i wasn't typing fast enough. Never noticed this before. But, it's still normal behaviour. IOW, there's no reason to change it for slowuser; different letters jump to different entries. DDLs are *not* designed for multiple-letter input. The odd behaviour is that is doesn't jump for fastuser.